# watermark in php is not uniform on all images

Tags: php, image, watermark

I am trying to create `watermark` on images programmatically in `PHP`. Images are uploaded by `users` and they can be of different dimensions. What I am doing to create a `watermark` is this:

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp381x387.png');
$ext = substr(strrchr($_GET['src'], '.'), 1);

if ($ext == 'png') {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['src']);
} else if ($ext == 'jpg') {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);
}

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 0;
$marge_bottom = 0;
$sx = imagesx($stamp); //width
$sy = imagesy($stamp); //height
// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, (imagesx($im) - $sx ) / 2, (imagesy($im) - $sy) / 2, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory

if ($ext == 'png') {
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
} else if ($ext == 'jpg') {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Now, it creates water mark on images but those are not uniform. See attached Images.
[image]

[image]

How to make it uniform on all `images`? any help?

Comment: resize images, before applying watermark.

Comment: any other better solution in which i dont have to resize images?? @MuhammedM.

Comment: You can use verot's class and avoid all the position calculations:
http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

Comment: @timhysniu care to share some link for that class?

Comment: Official documentation is here: https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php
You are able to initialize it with physical path to the image. Then you specify watermark and finally process that image. There are plenty of examples in that documentation. IMO, it's best to use a wrapper class for this type of thing, if that class is reputable enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

Here's a good example for adding watermark on images using PHP -
http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: it adds it in the bottom right corner of the image, what i want is the watermark to be in the center as my code above does. the problem here is it is not uniform on different image dimensions.